# build opencv with extra modules error ocv_download

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to build openCV with Extramodules. If I try to configure the projectfiles (vc14 x32 on windows 10) with cmake there's the error:

CMake Error at opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/cmake/download_vgg.cmake:13 (ocv_download):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_download".

Did anyone ever have this problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: have you downloaded the opencv_contrib from git ?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is you are using incompatible versions of opencv and opencv_contrib, you might be installing current version of opencv_contrib on maybe opencv2.4.xx

Answer (score 1):

Well, the download link for opencv contrib in CMake script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/fccf7cd6a4b12079f73bbfb21745f9babcd4eb1d now is 400: Invalid request.

From the commit https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/593e78c5d084aa0a29eb1e0459fc7f7a4dd52ea8 you can try to ignore the added line in CMakeLists **include(cmake/download_vgg.cmake)** and rebuild.

The below is basing on my experience, I'm not sure it will works for OpenCV 3.0.

Maybe you can try to clone [opencv contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) from git, then copy it to somewhere (for example modules directory in opencv source code). Then use CMAKE to set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH. If the hash is correct then it won't download and use the offline package.

I have try and build success OpenCV 2.x with IPP.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow instructions [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). 
Make sure you have active internet connection while building Opencv with contrib module.
When you hit config button on cmake(gui), it downloads other files like
vgg_generated_...
boostdesc_binboost_...
boostdesc_lbgm.i

P.S:  i compiled Opencv 3.1 with contrib. Cmake downloaded required files & configure was Done.