# How install OpenCV_contrib modules after installing opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, opencv3.0

I decided use some extra modules of opencv so i should install `OPENCV_CONTRIB` firstly,
I Downloaded contrib from [this github repo.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) and extracted the same directory which i installed opencv.

```
opencv files : /programs/opencv3.0
opencv build:  /programs/opencv3.0/build
contrib folder:/programs/opencv3.0/opencv_contrib_master
```

and then i added extra module path in CMake and while i press Configure button, i got an error:
Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid

and in the bottom window there is this error:

```
CMake Error at opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake:32 (ocv_download):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_download".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)
```

please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build opencv with extra modules error ocv\_download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194414/build-opencv-with-extra-modules-error-ocv-download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to work with the head/master version (or at least sources) in order to keep **opencv** and **opencv contrib** synced, and because releases of opencv contrib are not that frequent. If you're planning to keep it automatically updated, you might want to use scripts. In a bash script (update.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd opencv && git pull
cd ../opencv_contrib && git pull
```

then with powershell:

```
$src = "I:/opencv-master/opencv"
$srcextra = "I:/opencv-master/opencv/opencv_contrib"
$build = "I:/opencv-master/build"
$target = "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
bash update.sh
cd $build

rm -Recurse -Force CMake*
cmake -G $target -T v140,host=x64 `
    -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=1 `
    -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="../opencv_contrib/modules" `
    ../opencv | Tee-Object -Variable RESULT
if("$RESULT" -eq 1)
{
    "cmake didn't succeed, exiting."
    exit
}
msbuild.exe OpenCV.sln /verbosity:m /m
cd ..
```

then all you have to do is to run the powershell script. Feel free to adjust your cmake configuration with variables `-DXXX` to match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install contrib modules, which were released in 3.1 and changed a lot in 3.2. (google protobuff for nn is new feature)
So it might be a problem to build it now.
I built 3.2 with contrib on friday and it worked well. Just follow this tutorial very carefully  : http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html